# Returning integer value that represents the first non-null field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I've created the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExampleSP]
(
    @SearchText NVARCHAR(4000),
    @ID INT = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
deID,
deTitle
FROM tblDemo As de
LEFT JOIN tblLinkTable As lnk ON (lnk.ID = de.deID)
WHERE CONTAINS(cstKeywords, @SearchText)
AND ((@ID IS NULL) OR (lnk.ID = @ID))
GROUP BY deID,Title 
ORDER BY de.Title
```

But I also need to be able to find the first field that is not null out of the following table columns:

*deIntroText, deCompanyText, deTimetableText and deExampleText*

And i need to do this for each record that is returned from the SELECT.

So I realise that i'd need to create a temporary column to store it in and i guess you'd need to use an IF statement like this:

```
IF deIntroText IS NOT Null 
THEN TempFieldToReturn = 1

ELSE IF deCompanyText IS NOT Null 
THEN TempFieldToReturn = 2

ELSE IF deTimetableText IS NOT Null 
THEN TempFieldToReturn = 3

ELSE IF deExampleText IS NOT Null
THEN TempFieldToReturn = 4
```

So my question is - what is the best way to achieve this?  Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't perform that on data access layer, not data layer itself?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No real shortcut - just use a [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression:

```
SELECT
   /* Other Columns */
  CASE
    WHEN deIntroText IS NOT Null THEN 1
    WHEN deCompanyText IS NOT Null THEN 2
    WHEN deTimetableText IS NOT Null THEN 3
    WHEN deExampleText IS NOT Null THEN 4
  ELSE 5 END as OtherColumn
FROM
  /* Rest of query */
```

This is a Searched `CASE` - there are actually two variants of `CASE`. I guessed at 5 if all of the columns are `NULL` - you might leave off the `ELSE 5` portion, if you want a `NULL` result in such a case.

Comment: +1 If CHARINDEX or PATINDEX is anything to go by, `ELSE 0` could be an option too.